# Can't visualize raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster and I'm trying to visualize it on QGIS.
For some reason I can only visualize the raster if I upload it alone without any other layer. If I add BING layer, it can't load due to python layer. If I upload first the BING and then the layer, the layer ''added'' but I can't see it.

I tried to save again my raster as WGS84 but  and also to register it with the BING and it didn't have any error, but still I can't see the results together, only if I upload it without the BING.

Comment: right click the raster in layer list and choose "zoom on layer". Does it appear in the canvas? Is it at the correct location? Also please explain what you mean by "cant load due to python layer". By "upload" do you mean "add"?

Comment: probably, your projection is wrong or missing. Adding bing will automatically change the map projection to epsg:3857

Comment: Have you enabled `on the fly reprojection`?